# Why am I getting a IntegrityError at, null value in a column that doesn't exists... Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to hit an external api, when a user submits a form.
I am using Django and Postgresql

**My Model**

```
class League_Mod(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Espn_League_Id = models.IntegerField(unique = True)
    Espn_S2 = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    Espn_Swid = models.CharField(max_length=300) 
    bigdata = models.JSONField(default=dict,null=True)
```

**My Serializer**

```
    class Meta:
        model = League_Mod
        fields = ['host', 'Espn_League_Id','Espn_S2','Espn_Swid','bigdata']
```

**Views**

where Owners is a large dictionary.

```
league_data = {
            'host' : request.data['host'],
            'Espn_League_Id' :request.data['Espn_League_Id'],
            'Espn_S2' : request.data['Espn_S2'],
            'Espn_Swid' : request.data['Espn_Swid'],
            'bigdata' : Owners
  }
serializer = LeagueSerializer(data=league_data)
print(serializer)
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    serializer.save()
    return  Response(serializer.data)
```

my print serializer runs, and prints the data correctly.

But I get an error:

```
integrityError at /wel/
null value in column "hello" of relation "api_league_mod" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (11, JPFL, 216415, AEAylLD7uSQQ7%2BenPr6av1H%2Fx0Hqbbpn8Jvr91ngxM1ll5ynO685mhN%2BSu..., {D19D67CA-C981-4CA2-8463-AF4111D2E8E2}, {"Person1": {"2010": [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6,..., null).
```

I am very unclear where the column hello is... and there is no relation to api_league_mod Model, so don't quite understand why my serializer is returning unvalid

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `hello` is probably present in the database, which means it was in your `League_Mod` model and was removed later. This removal however is not reflected in any of your migrations.

You could try to run `manage.py makemigrations` and check the output, it might create the delete operation for the `hello` field.

Then run `manage.py migrate` to apply the changes to the DB

Comment: Hey Simone, thanks for the quick response. This unfortunately is not the case. I just looked back through my migrations, and there was never a 'hello' column.

Comment: JUST KIdding. Checked the table in postgres and sure enough there is a column called hello... how it got there I don't know. Good looks!